# Run macro on active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make this work in the active cell. I want to define the number of cells that it can choose either it can be 6 as below or 20 or any number that I define before running the macro."

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+z
'
ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=";", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1))
Selection.Offset(0, 6).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Selection.Offset(0, 6).Select
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you honestly need both tab and semi-colon as delimiters or was the tab just a leftover because it was pre-selected when you recorded the macro?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Text to Columns to split the data based on a semi-colon delimiter¹ and only keep the last value. It also seems that you are leaving a blank row after completing the split so I'll give you the option to avoid that.

```
Sub Macro3()
' Macro3 Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+z

    Dim vVALs As Variant

    'option 1 - replace active cell with last split value
    With Selection.Cells(1, 1)
        If CBool(Len(.Value)) Then
            vVALs = Split(.Value, Chr(59)) 'split on a semi-colon
            .Cells = vVALs(UBound(vVALs))
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Sub Macro4()
' Macro4 Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+z

    Dim vVALs As Variant

    'option 2 - put last split value into row below, clear active cell
    With Selection.Cells(1, 1)
        If CBool(Len(.Value)) Then
            vVALs = Split(.Value, Chr(59)) 'split on a semi-colon
            .Cells.Offset(1, 0) = vVALs(UBound(vVALs))
            .Cells.ClearContents
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

I've used `Selection.Cells(1, 1)` in case more than a single cell is currently selected. This will take the first cell in any selection set regardless of whether there is only one cell or more than one cell. This could be modified to loop through multiple cells in a selection set is need be but additional error control should be applied to ensure that teh operations are going to be performed without choking on a bad selection of values.

I'm checking that the value in the selected cell has at least one character as anything that is there will split to at least single value even if it does not contain a semi-colon but no value at all will not split.

¹ <sub>there actually is a semi-colon option, you don't need to use *Other:* to specify it</sub>